# Easiest way to draw a line in "rubberbanding" style onto a racket canvas

Tags: racket

Does anybody have any pointers on how to draw (in Racket) in "rubberband" mode.  I'd prefer to not use any kind of backbuffer and flip operations.  Back in the day, the XOR raster operation was used.  You'd draw your line (or other figure) once in XOR mode and to remove it you'd draw it again (in XOR mode).  This was useful when you wanted users to draw lines, circles, etc. and size them by stretching or "rubberbanding".  The Racket docs seem to indicate that a style of "xor" isn't supported by a pen% or brush%

Thanks.

Comment: The xor style was removed with the switch to cairo, IIRC.  In any case, for such questions it's probably best to ask on the [mailing list](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/).